# Azure Search Query Latency

Tags: performance, rest, azure-cognitive-search, latency

I am developing the search functionality for an e-commerce website and have gotten to a point where I am looking to optimize performance. I am using Azure Search with a REST call for the search functionality.

Microsoft's [performance benchmarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/performance-benchmarks#benchmark-1-e-commerce-search) indicate a similar use case with 6M documents, 20GB index size, among other details. For S1 tier performance, it indicates low-load performance of about 100ms average latency, with 25th and 75th percentiles of 35ms and 115ms, respectively.

In my use case, I have 700K documents and a 7GB index size. For S1 tier performance at low-load (single user making consecutive requests) I am getting performance of about 600ms average latency, with 25th and 75th percentiles of 250ms and 1000ms, respectively.

**What can I do to achieve performance comparable to the Microsoft benchmarks?**

I have tried multiple tests. I first thought it was because I was using Regex queries, so I switched from a partial match approach to a keyword only approach. However, this improved performance only marginally.

I also thought it might be due to the large number of facets included in the index. I built a duplicate index which excluded the facets, however, again, this did not result in noticeable improvements in performance.

I also tested if the performance has to do with the size of the index, either the number of documents or size of the documents. I created another index based on a smaller table in our database, with only 300 documents and 3 columns with short text fields. In this case, I was able to get down to about 200 ms latency, but still not as good as the benchmarks, plus I would expect significantly better performance given the small size.

At this point, I don't believe it is so much an issue with my index structure as it is an issue with system performance. I'm using 3 replicas and 4 partitions, so I should be getting decent coverage and availability. Again, we are unloaded at this point, so query overload isn't the issue. What changes can be made to the infrastructure to improve this performance?

In case the query itself can be improved, here is an example REST call:

```
my.index?api-version=2021-04-30-Preview&search=cpu&$select=ProductId,ProductName,ProductDescription,ProductCategoryDisplayName,ProductManufacturerDisplayName,Price,Quantity,ImageType,ImageURL&$count=true&queryType=full&$top=10&$skip=0
```

Comment: The numbers indeed look high and it's also surprising that the tiny dataset isn't even faster. Are client and server in the same region? The Cognitive Search response headers include an "elapsed-time" response header with the server-side latency in milliseconds, that number can help separate network latency from server-side latency.

Comment: @PabloCastro I double checked with the header data, and even subtracting network latency, I'm still getting a response time of about 500ms.

Comment: hmm, your last test with just 300 docs and 3 columns should see all immediate results since you effectively removed all potential sources of latency. If you're open to share your index schema and test data, I'm happy to run them on my side and see what numbers I get.